# Meteor - #each iteration of an array with another HTML element inserted after each nth item

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, each, meteor-blaze

I'm iterating over an array of items in Meteor using Blaze using the #each iterator, and I want to insert an HTML element after each nth (10th) item. I figured I could use @index to access what index of the array I'm at, but don't really know how to insert another element every 10th element.

```
{{#each getArray}}
  <div class="item" data-value="{{someHelper @index}}">{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: By element do you mean an HTML element?

Comment: Yes. For example div element with a banner ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it seems like you'd want to make a custom helper that returns whether or not you should have an element in the DOM:

```
{{#each getArray}}
  <div class="item" data-value="{{someHelper @index}}">{{this}}</div>
  {{#if shouldAddDiv @index}}
    <div>I was after the 10th item!</div>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}

Template.TemplateName.helpers({
  shouldAddDiv(index) {
    if(index % 10 === 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

If you don't want the div to appear after the first element, you'd change the `index % 10` to `index % 9`

Comment: Thanks, works great! Maybe a little improvement instead of if/else - return (index > 0 && index % 10 == 0) || false;

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo (%), which takes the remainder of two numbers. For example 11%3 = 2, because 3 fits 3 times in 11, leaving 2 aka the remainder.

```
Template.TemplateName.helpers({
    'someHelper': function(whichOne){
        if (whichOne%10 == 0){
            yourArray.push(<newElement>);
        }
    }
});
```

Whenever whichOne%10 is zero, you've hit the tenth element in your array.

Comment: that's a good idea, but I want to insert HTML element in the DOM after each 10th item in the array. I didn't explain it correctly.